# Remove letters from string 'peshoishere' with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, printing, character, letter

Each time i find a sequence of  characters 'eho' , 'piere' remove it from the initial string and print the modified string.Which is the best method to do it in javascript?

**Input**
peshoishere
eho
piere
**Output**
psishere
ssh

Comment: are you sure you want to retrieve "eho" and "piere"? there is no "eho" in "peshoishere "

Comment: Yes I a sure - here is the task : You will receive a string title which contains only small latin letters [a-z]. After that you will have to read from the input N lines of text. For each of these lines, your task is to find out if there is such a sequence in the string you receive as input on the first line (title). The sequence may not be on consecutive indices. Each time you find a sequence of these characters you remove it from the initial string and print the modified string. If no such sequence is found you have to print No such title found! and not modify the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = input.replace(/eho/g, '').replace(/piere/g, '');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

you need to do this as a RegExp to replace ALL instances of the the pattern

Comment: what if the `e` of `eho` is the last `e` of `piere`? "piereho" -> "", not "pier"

Comment: also not clear what happens to `e(s)ho` from the example

Comment: yes, I voted up that comment, guessing typo in the question? Voted to close for clarity/focus.